# Header Location resulting in a 404 error

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I've tried to use the header function. But it will display an error message when I click on the login button.
My login document is in: XAMPP\htdocs\Website\includes\login.inc.php
My index document is in: XAMPP\htdocs\Website\index.php

Hopefully is someone able to help.

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'dbh.inc.php';

$gebr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gebr']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//Foutmeldingen
    //Check of de velden leeg zijn
    if (empty($gebr) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM stemmer WHERE Naam='$gebr'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                if ($row['Wachtwoord'] != $pwd) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                    exit();
                } else{
                    //Log de gebruiker hier in
                    $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['idStemmer'];
                    $_SESSION['u_naam'] = $row['Naam'];
                    $_SESSION['u_gemeente'] = $row['idGemeente'];
                    $_SESSION['u_partij'] = $row['idPartij'];

                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {

    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the error message?  They have a purpose.   Keep in mind, headers cannot be sent after a body, so you cannot have anything printed out before your headers, including whitespaces in any files before `<?php`

Comment: Error 404. URL wasn't found on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're including a file, the URI is unchanged.  So you still reference links or locations based on the URI you loaded.

Based on your 404 error, it's likely that you're including this file from the same web directory as index.php, so the location should not be set to `../index.php?login=error` which would be trying to go one directory back but `index.php?login=error` which would try to load the index.php in the same web directory.

You could also use `/index.php?login=error` (`/` prefix) which would load the index.php from the web root directory.  If you're going to be loading this include file in many different files, it's best to use root relative paths like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering to get around this problem, with the overhead of all of your output to the browser being buffered in the server until you send it. You can do this by calling ob_start() and ob_end_flush() in your script, or setting the output_buffering configuration directive on in your php.ini or server configuration files.

Use `ob_start()`

For More Read This **[Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes)**

Comment: Not sure if this helps with the error 'Error 404. URL wasn't found on server.' in OP's comments.